# Celery - Specify task parent manually?

Tags: python, celery

I'm running a group of tasks in Celery like so:

```py
def run_many(n):
    job_id = str(uuid4())
    g = group(dummy.s(job_id) for _ in range(n))
    job = task.apply_async(task_id=job_id)
    job.save() # so children are accessible later in the GroupResult

@app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def dummy(self, job_id):
    outputdir = Path(job_id/self.request.id).resolve()
    print(f"dummy: {self.request.id}")
    # do some work and write results into outputdir
```

I monitor the state of the whole deal like this:

```py
def check_job_status(job_id):
    job = GroupResult.restore(id=job_id, app=app)
    n_total = len(job.children)
    n_finished = job.completed_count()
    status = "SUCCESS" if n_finished == n_total else "RUNNING"
    return status, n_finished/n_total
```

I'd like to be able to get information about an individual task, including the `id` of the job that created it, but I can't figure out how to store that information:

```py
def check_task_status(task_id):
    result = AsyncResult(id=task_id, app=app)
```

in that function, `result.parent` is `None` even if I set `self.parent = job_id` in `dummy()`.

Is there some way to store custom metadata for a task that get ends up getting written to the backend and loaded by `AsyncResult`? I know that I can use `update_state(state, meta)`, but creating that `meta` dictionary with a `job_id` key each time I want to update the task state seems cumbersome, particularly if I want to update the state from called functions because then I have to pass the `job_id` around. If I could access a task's current `meta` dictionary from within the task, I could just `update()` the dictionary, but I don't know how to retrieve that dictionary from within the task itself.

Any ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly do something like this (but this method for getting meta is marked as internal):

```py
@app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def dummy(self, job_id):
    outputdir = Path(job_id/self.request.id).resolve()
    print(f"dummy: {self.request.id}")
    # do some work and write results into outputdir

    from celery.app.task import Context
    from celery.backends.s3 import S3Backend
    from celery.backends.base import KeyValueStoreBackend, BaseKeyValueStoreBackend

    request: Context = self.request
    # I use the S3Backend but you may use another
    backend: S3Backend | KeyValueStoreBackend | BaseKeyValueStoreBackend = self.backend
    meta = backend._get_result_meta(
        result=None, state="STARTED", traceback=None, request=request
    )
    meta["parent_id"] = job_id
    self.update_state(task_id=request.id, state="STARTED", meta=meta)
```

you may also find this interesting depending on what backend and broker you are using: https://github.com/celery/celery/discussions/7388

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a custom class inheriting from `Task` to override the `update_state()` method and always include `job_id` in `meta`. I also added a bit that stores the `job_id` from the `group` id before the job is started so that I don't have to pass in the `job_id` anymore.

```py
class InnerTask(Task):
    def before_start(self, task_id, args, kwargs):
        self.job_id = self.request.group
        return super().before_start(task_id, args, kwargs)

    def update_state(self, task_id=None, state=None, meta=None, **kwargs):
        """Update task state.
        ALways includes the job_id of the task in meta.

        Arguments:
            task_id (str): Id of the task to update.
                Defaults to the id of the current task.
            state (str): New state.
            meta (Dict): State meta-data.
        """
        if task_id is None:
            task_id = self.request.id
        if meta:
            meta.update({"job_id": self.job_id})
        else:
            meta = {"job_id": self.job_id}
        self.backend.store_result(task_id, meta, state, request=self.request, **kwargs)


@app.task(base=InnerTask, bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def dummy(self):
    outputdir = Path(self.job_id/self.request.id).resolve()
    print(f"dummy: {self.request.id}")
    # do some work and write results into outputdir
```

It isn't quite as generic as I'd like because if the task isn't started from a `group` it'll fail, but it gets the job done.